# Invalid escape sequence in literal Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, string, escaping, sequence

hello i am using swift 3.0 ,i want something like this
    `"xxx\something.com"`
 how do i get that?, i wrote like this,

```
 static let x = "xxx\something.com"
```

getting Invalid escape sequence in literal error.i did some workaround no 
     luck please help

Comment: You need "xxx\\something.com" with 2 backslashes for it to escape

Comment: Search for "special characters" in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html.

Comment: thanks Jake and martin works like a charm

Comment: Jake's answer is the correct one, `\b` becomes `\\b`.

Comment: need to do `#"This is a Backslash: \"#` (add # on the beginning or on the end) or `"This is a Backslash: \\"` (write double slash)